# Скриптовые языки в разработке игр

Tags: разработка-игр

Заинтересовался темой разработки игр. И вот один из моментов мне остался не понятным. В чем смысл использования скриптовых языков при разработки игр и какая от них польза? Да и вообще, чем руководствуются люди при выборе скриптового языка (насколько мне известно самые популярные — это Lua, Python и JS)?

Единственный плюс, который я вижу в использовании скриптовых языков — это то, что их не нужно перекомпилировать. К примеру если огромной движок на С/C++ и его перекомпиляция занимает пару часов. Ну а как же скорость? Все же говорят, что в разработке игр кругом одна оптимизация?

В некоторых источниках было написано, что используется для разделения логики игры, толком не понял какая логика имеется в виду…

В общем, хотелось бы, чтобы кто-нибудь разъяснил этот вопрос подробно. Или, хотя бы, привел источники, где обо всем этом можно узнать.

Comment: Уточните, какие именно применения скриптовых языков вас интересуют? Например есть игры на написанные на СЯ, есть СЯ в подсистемах игр, есть СЯ в пользовательских картах-миссиях, в модах, и т.п.

Comment: В целом применение скриптовых языков в gamedev, различные игры от шутеров до аркад. Просто хочу понять идеалогию этого, а не отношение к определенной тематике.

Comment: _в GameDev кругом одна оптимизация_ - ай, спасибо, давно так не смеялся.

Comment: Скриптовые языки предоставляют возможность моддинга игры. S.T.A.L.K.E.R., например, использует Lua. Собственно, благодаря этому и появились тысячи модов, благодаря которым игра до сих пор жива.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В первую очередь скриптовый язык позволяет отделить игровую логику, от всего остального (графики, физиики, ИИ, ввода/вывода, сетевого взаимодействия). Важно заметить, что игровая логика с точки зрения сложности кода и алгоритмов гораздо проще и оперирует простыми и понятными абстракциями, например: Персонаж, Здоровье, Скорость движения, Оружие,  Инвентарь.

Пока вы разрабатываете игру в одиночку, использование скриптового языка может поначалу показаться не очень полезным. Но уже дает вам возможность экспериментировать с игровой механикой, не пересобирая весь проект (а если все сделать хорошо, то и не перезапуская игру).

Когда дело касается большой команды разработчиков, то появляется разделение труда и, что немаловажно, бюджет. Тут оказывается, что:

- каждый час потраченный на пересборку проекта стоит денег;
- программисты графики/"движка", геймплея и скриптовых сцен стоят разных денег;
- геймдизайнеры/левелдизайнеры могут писать скрипты;
- геймдизайнеры постоянно что-то хотят менять и ребалансировать.

Тут скриптовые языки и раскрываются во всей красе.

Что касается производительности и оптимизаций, то важно отметить следующие моменты:

- игровая логика обычно не содержит сложных тяжелых вычислений;
- скриптовые языки имеют очень неплохие JIT-компиляторы, которые во время выполнения игры превращают скрипт в машинный код (и тут доступны более агрессивные оптимизации, чем даже при статической компиляции);
- действительно сложные или требующие высокой производительности части (какой-нибудь условный поиск пути) можно унести в движок, доверив разработку опытным алгоритмистам, и позволить вызывать их из скриптового окружения.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но а каким образом происходит связывание к примеру кода движка и скриптовых языков? Получается, что скриптовые языки вызывают какие-либо методы движка и уже ими оперируют для создания какой-либо логики. Я правильно это понимаю?

Comment: Верно. И наоборот: движок может вызывать заранее оговоренные функции в скрипте, где разработчик уже как-то обрабатывает вызов.